# install arcgisbinding package in R version 3.5.0,get warning: as ‘lib’ is unspecified,package ‘‘arcgisbinding’ is not available

Tags: r, arcgis

I try to install "arcgisbinding" package in R version 3.5.0. But I failed, get the following error and warning.

> *Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Lenovo/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘‘arcgisbinding’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)*

I also try to install this package in R version 3.4.3, get the same error and warning. I thought the main reason for this is the ‘lib’ is unspecified.

I am confused because that the "arcgisbinding" package can be installed on R >= 3.2, based on the introduction of the official website - [PDF](https://r-arcgis.github.io/assets/arcgisbinding.pdf).

Could anyone help me? Thanks so much.

Comment: I don't think this package is installable from CRAN using `install.packages`. [This appears to be the installation guide](https://github.com/R-ArcGIS/r-bridge-install).

Comment: @neilfws   Thank you so much.  Is it a good choice to install a package from GitHub? It is the first time I know this install method. Why do not they add their package in CRAN?

Comment: It's an unusual method and it looks like you have to do it through the ArcGIS software.

Comment: @neilfws  Do you know other packages like "arcgisbinding"? I wanna give up this package, choose a simple one.

Answer (score 6):

First, download the "arcgisbinding" package manually from GitHub: https://github.com/R-ArcGIS/r-bridge/releases/tag/v1.0.1.232.
Second, install this package in Rstudio using the menu "Tools">"install packages", and then choose the downloaded package archive. The installation is very fast.